# Diferencia entre poner los paréntesis dentro o fuera en una función anónima auto-ejecutable

Tags: javascript

Hoy en el trabajo me he encontrado con una duda sobre el siguiente código (simplificado):

```js
(function() { console.log("1"); })();
(function() { console.log("2"); }());
```

Son dos funciones anónimas que se ejecutan automáticamente. El código fue escrito por el mismo desarrollador y, a simple vista, me parece que no hay diferencia entre un método o el otro, pero no sé si eso es correcto.

¿Existen diferencias entre esas dos funciones anónimas? ¿Por qué un mismo desarrollador las usaría de forma diferente?

Comment: Según [esta pregunta en SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) no hay mayor diferencia más allá que simple sintaxis.

Comment: @guzgarcia genial. Pon eso como respuesta (con la información indicada en el enlace) y la acepto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambas formas hacen exactamente lo mismo pero el orden en el que se ejecutan los pasos es distinto.

**Forma 1**

```
(function() { console.log("1"); })();
```

En la primera forma tenemos una función, la ponemos entre paréntesis y luego la ejecutamos, de forma simplificada se podría ver así `(f)();`, siendo `f` la función.

**Forma 2**

```
(function() { console.log("2"); }());
```

En la segunda forma tenemos la misma función pero ahora no está entre paréntesis antes de ser ejecutada si no que ahora metemos entre paréntesis el resultado después de la ejecución, de forma simplificada se vería así: `(f())`.

Resumiendo, en la primera forma agrupamos y ejecutamos mientras que en la segunda forma ejecutamos y luego agrupamos.

Answer (score 1):

Es mas o menos igual, lo que importa es que empezar una línea con paréntesis, abre sitio a una Expresión, que no es igual que una Sentencia.

```js
 (7==8);//esto es aceptable;
 console.log("compiló, es expresión pero no es función por tanto no auto ejecutable!!");
```

Pero lo anterior no es auto ejecutable.
  Una función, es expresión, y también por otro lado es auto ejecutable.
  La expresión, puede ser anidada siempre que lo que retorne sea una expresión.

Incluso se pueden anidar ilmitadamente:

```js
 (((((((function() { console.log("3"); })))))))();
 (((((((function() { console.log("4"); }())))))));
```

Incluso los otros paréntesis, del invoker, estan permitidos en cualquier punto de la cadena, siempre que el anidamiento resulte en una expresión autonivocable, debido a que devuelven una función que también es expresión

```js
 ((((((((((((function() { console.log("5"); })))))))())))));
```

La función al ser expresión puede ser comparada dentro de otra expresión

```js
 (((((function() { console.log("6"); })()==7))));
```

Así que a grande rasgos, es igual, talvez la opción 2 sea más legible, pero no difieren demasiado